# Why the painting of a background image in an embedded app causes a performance drop after migration to Qt 5.9.3?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, embedded, qpixmap

My app is working on an embedded system. I have migrated the app from Qt 5.6 to Qt 5.9.3 and it became very slow. I have checked the output of the `top` command and realized that my app is causing a CPU utilization of 100%.

So, I have check my app and I have found a problem in this part of the code:

```
MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
...

    QPixmap bg(BACK_IMG_PATH);
    bg.fill(Qt::transparent);
    QPalette p(palette());
    p.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bg);
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
    setPalette(p);
...
}
```

The problem is, that if I add the code for the background, my app becomes extremely slow. However, if I remove this code, my app is working as expected. This cannot be a solution though, cause I need the background.

This problem did not exist before the migration.

I have tried to solve this by reimplementing the `paintEvent` and using *QPainter* like this:

```
void MainWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawImage(QRectF(this->x(), this->y(), this->width(), this->height()), QImage("img/bg_1280_720.png"));
}
```

This result is slightly faster, but still not satisfactory (the cpu utilization is 50%).

How to solve this problem?

Comment: One idea to speed it up is instead of loading the image from file every time you paint it you could load it in the constructor and store it in a member variable

Comment: If this is a performance *regression* you should probably look into the changelog of QT, check its mailing lists, etc.  Ideally see if you can develop a minimal piece of code which shows a large performance difference between versions - if you have that, and the issue is original, then you have the basis of a helpful report to the developers.   But you need to have minimal code that demonstrates a difference which they can try, and you need to thoroughly check to make sure it is not a knows issue *or a difference in something you need to do in using the two versions*.